# Mysql columns as rows (pivot table) query very slow when records is very huge

Tags: mysql, performance, dynamic, pivot

I am trying to write a query to create a 'table' of data as follows:

```
SELECT cs.`category_id`, cs.`ProcessDate`, cs.`PercentChange`
  FROM `Category_Statistics` cs
 WHERE cs.`ProcessDate` >= '2011-05-10'
   AND cs.`ProcessDate` <= '2011-05-14'
```

Which would return something like:

```
CategoryId  |  ProcessDate  | PercentChange
-------------------------------------------
category_4  |  2011-05-10   |      10
category_4  |  2011-05-11   |      18
category_4  |  2011-05012   |      12
...
category_7  |  2011-05-10   |      21
category_7  |  2011-05-11   |      7
...
category_12 |  2011-05-10   |      7
category_12 |  2011-05-11   |      15
```

Now I want the results to be something like this (from a MySQL query, not manipulated by the app):

```
CategoryId    | 2011-05-10 | 2011-05-11 | 2011-05-12 | 2011-05-13 | 2011-05-14 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
category_4    |     10     |     18     |     12     |      9     |      14    |
category_7    |     21     |      7     |     16     |      14    |      13    |
categeory_12  |      7     |     15     |     11     |      19    |       8    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have query to build the above result. This is my query.

```
SELECT `CategoryId`,
   MAX(IF(c.`ProcessedOn` = '2011-04-20', c.`PercentChange`, NULL)) AS '2011-04-20',
   MAX(IF(c.`ProcessedOn` = '2011-04-21', c.`PercentChange`, NULL)) AS '2011-04-21',
   MAX(IF(c.`ProcessedOn` = '2011-04-22', c.`PercentChange`, NULL)) AS '2011-04-22',
   MAX(IF(c.`ProcessedOn` = '2011-04-23', c.`PercentChange`, NULL)) AS '2011-04-23',
   MAX(IF(c.`ProcessedOn` = '2011-04-24', c.`PercentChange`, NULL)) AS '2011-04-24'
  FROM `Category_Gravity` c
 WHERE c.`ProcessedOn` >= '2011-04-20'
   AND c.`ProcessedOn` <= '2011-04-24'
 GROUP BY `CategoryId`
```

This query is working fine when I have 20 or 100 records. But In the case of if record count is lakhs and more , it is getting slow.. I have to wait for 10 min to view query result. Please  give any suggestion to fast up my query or give me better query to build my result.